# Centering Elements Vertically with FlexBox

Tags: css, flexbox

Attempting to use FlexBox *(for demo purposes only)*. However I'm having trouble vertically centering text within the parent `.top-nav-bar`. Using `justify-content: space-between` I'm able to get the 2 elements where I need them horizontally, however I'm having no luck centering `.contact` and `.help` vertically within `.top-nav-bar`. All attempts to do so seem to butt the text up against the top most edge of the page.

[Link To CodePen](http://codepen.io/bmoneruiux/full/pJJvpa/)

HTML:

```
  header.section1.box
    .top-nav-bar
      .contact
        p Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
      .help
        p Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
```

CSS:

```
.section1
  background:
    image: url(url/of/image.jpg)
    size: cover
    position: top center
    repeat: no-repeat
    attachment: fixed

.box
  overflow: hidden
  width: 100%
  height: 100vh
  background:
    color: #90281F

.top-nav-bar
  max-width: 1200px
  width: 100%
  height: 40px
  margin: 0 auto
  font-size: 0.813em
  background: pink
  display: flex
  flex-direction: row
  align-items: center
  justify-content: space-between

.contact
  background: red

.help
  background: green
```

Comment: Try setting the parent container to "display:table" and the child to "display:table-cell" then applying "vertical-align:middle" to the child.

    header.section1.box  
    .top-nav-bar (display:table)  
        .wrapper (display:table-cell)
            .contact
                p Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
              .help
                p Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet

Comment: But isn't FlexBox supposed to alleviate having to deal with displays and floats and other things like that?

Comment: I'm sure flexbox handles the main boxes' alignment in relation to the browser dimensions.. not sure exactly though, haven't used. Hope this helps.

Comment: You're making it really difficult for people to help you by posting that as HTML/CSS.

Comment: I wasn't aware. I'll place it into a CodePen for better understanding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> All attempts to do so seem to butt the text up against the top most
>   edge of the page.

But that's where `.top-nav-bar` is - it's a div whose height is `40px` (as defined in CSS) and has no content before it in the HTML, so it will always be on the top of the page.

If you set `.top-nav-bar { height: 100%; }` then `.top-nav-bar` will be the height of it's parent (`100vh`) and it's contents can then be vertically centered (which you have correctly instructed using `align-items: center`)

```css
    .section1 {
      background: url(url/of/image.jpg) top center no-repeat;
   background-size: cover;
   background-attachment: fixed;
  }

    .box {
      overflow: hidden;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100vh;
      background:#90281F;
 }
    
    .top-nav-bar {
      max-width: 1200px;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      margin: 0 auto;
      font-size: 0.813em;
      background: pink;
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: row;
      align-items: center;
      justify-content: space-between;
  }
      
    .contact {
      background: red
  }
    
    .help {
      background: green
  }
```

```html
  <header class="section1 box">
 <div class="top-nav-bar">
   <div class="contact">
  <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
   </div>
   <div class="help">
  <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
   </div>
 </div>
  </header>
```

Comment: Added the CodePen link to the OP for further understanding.

Comment: @bmoneruxui - use your inspector tool, your skeleton framework is adding a bottom margin of `2.5rem` to the bottom of your paragraphs in your `.top-nav-bar`....and in the pen, you don't actually have `.top-nav-bar { align-items: center; }` which is what vertically centers items in a flex row, relative to each other.

Comment: 0_o Thank you for this. In my defense I was using inspector in Safari (which I hate). Finally fixed it HOWEVER why when I placed margin:0 on the p tag did it not change? I actually had to place margin-bottom:0, and my CSS rules should be coming after Skeletons.